# Android Accessibility: How to make an image view not say it's an image?

Tags: android

I'm working on enhancing the accessibility for my app. I'm setting content description on all the image views. Sometimes the image views act as buttons, so I basically set the content description as something like "Book icon. Button. Double tap to open article.". However, it always appends the "image" to the end of it so it reads "Book icon. Button. Double tap to open article. IMAGE". Is there a way to override this and have it not say "image" at the end?